# Передача базового типа по ссылке

Tags: java

Как, в java, передать базовый тип по ссылке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Забоксить тип в соответствующий враппер-класс. int -> Integer, char -> Character и так далее. Примитивные типы всегда передаются по значению.

Comment: В Java **любые** аргументы передаются по значению http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference.

Comment: А смысл, ведь значение будет неизменяемо, и при попытке его изменить всёравно будет создавать новый объект с соответствующим значением!!!!